# Python Syntax Incorrect for Email Creation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write out some basic python for my kolab email server. For the primary_mail, I want it to be first initial last name, such as jdoe. The default is first name (dot) last name. john.doe@domain.com

I have came up the following:

```
    primary_mail ='%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s
```

Which I want to basically say jdoe@domain.com

```
givenname would be someone's full name. (i.e John)
surname would be someone's last name. (i.e Doe)
domain is the email domain. domain.com
```

When python goes to canonify it, it comes up with some mumbo jumbo like so:

```
    'john[0:1]'doe@domain.com
```

Can someone help me out with correcting this? I am so close.

EDIT:

According to kolab documentation, it looks like it is something like:

```
"{0}@{1}": "format('%(uid)s', '%(domain)s')"
```

This of course doesn't work for me though....

EDIT 2:

I am getting the following in my error logs:

```
imaps[1916]: ptload completely failed: unable to canonify identifier: 'john'[0:1]doe@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

String formatting is by far the easiest, most readable and preferred way of accomplishing this:

```
first_name = 'John'
surname = 'Smith'
domain = 'company.com'
primary_mail = '{initial}{surname}@{domain}'.format(initial=first_name[0].lower(), surname=surname.lower(), domain=domain)
```

primary_mail now equals 'jsmith@company.com'.  You define a string containing named placeholders in braces, then call the format method to have those placeholders replaced at runtime with the appropriate values.  Here, we take the first character of first_name and convert it to lower case, convert the entirety of surname also, and leave domain unchanged.

You can read more on string formatting at the [Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: Nope.. The only way it seems to work is if I put primary_mail ='%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s  in on the kolab webadmin.... it will show properly in the field: http://cl.ly/image/3y0m1b0t1H2N      but if I use yours, it just shows a @ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

James Scholes is right that `format` is a better way of doing it, however reading the Kolab documentation it seems that you can only give the format string, and they use the `%` style formatter internally, where you can't change it. From 
[the Kolab 'primary_mail' documentation](https://docs.kolab.org/administrator-guide/configuring-the-kolab-server.html?highlight=primary_mail)

```
primary_mail = %(givenname)s.%(surname)s@%(domain)s

The equivalent of the following Python is then executed:
primary_mail = "%(givenname)s.%(surname)s@%(domain)s" % {
    "givenname": "Maria",
    "surname": "Moller",
    "preferredlanguage": "en_US"
}
```

In this case, we need a modifier to the format conversation. We have `%(givenname)s`, which ensures that givenname is a string. We can also specify a minimum length, followed by a `.` and then a precision. This is normally only used it numbers, but we can use it for strings, too. Here is a format string with no minimum length, but a maximum length (precision) of 1 character:

```
"%(givenname).1s"
```

So you probably want a string like this:

```
"%(givenname).1s%(surname)@%(domain)"
```

Comment: Nope.. The only way it seems to work is if I put primary_mail ='%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s  in on the kolab webadmin.... it will show properly in the field: http://cl.ly/image/3y0m1b0t1H2N      but if I use yours, it just shows a @ symbol.

Comment: If they're not using python's own string formatting, it will be difficult to work out - although you've just said your example from the question does work, so maybe I'm missing what you need to do?

Comment: It shows properly in the web interface, but I am getting: imaps[1916]: ptload completely failed: unable to canonify identifier: 'john'[0:1]doe@domain.com

Comment: I suggest a bug report with Kolab, if the same formatting string is used differently in the web UI and in their imap server.

Comment: I did :) I just didn't know if I was being stupid or not. Is my original incorrect though? Where I said "i had came up with the following" ?

Comment: I can't say why the web interface is showing jdoe, when I put it in python as `primary_mail = "'%(givenname)s'[0:1]%(surname)s@%(domain)s" % { "givenname": "john", "surname": "doe", "domain": "example.org" }` then I get the same string as your imaps error message: `'john'[0:1]doe@example.org`

Comment: And yours: primary_mail = "%(givenname).1s%(surname)@%(domain)" works? Thats interesting.. Let me try yours again. thanks for your help man